# Is using a phone while driving more dangerous than driving while drunk?

Tags: road-vehicles, safety, mobile-phones, driving

There have been numerous studies that show how using a phone while driving is [more distracting than other non-driving tasks](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/485/is-talking-and-driving-more-dangerous-than-any-other-type-of-distraction) and even worse than driving while intoxicated.

[Here was a study done in the US](http://cellphonefreedriving.ca/media/fatal_distraction.pdf):

> When controlling for driving difficulty and time on task, cell-phone drivers exhibited
>   greater impairment than intoxicated drivers.

[And one in the UK](http://trid.trb.org/view.aspx?id=733342):

> Drivers also reported that it was easier to drive drunk than to drive while using a phone. It is concluded that driving behaviour is impaired more during a phone conversation than by having a blood alcohol level at the UK legal limit (80mg / 100ml).

However, these are all studies where the researchers created situations analogous to driving in real traffic. **Is there any *naturalistic* evidence that shows one way or the other that the tests done in controlled conditions translate into the real world?**

Comment: What kind of evidence would you expect?

Comment: "I would expect a strong correlation in accident rates with phone usage trending upwards over the past 20 years": But there are [confounding factors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confounding_factor) galore.  Many advances in auto safety have been made over the past 20 years (airbags, antilock brakes, traction control, etc), so even if phones *tended* to increase the accident rate, other factors might drive the rate down overall.  Without cell phones, perhaps the rate would have decreased even more.

Comment: I'd love a question on this topic, but this one is a bit confused right now. You ask in the title whether the claims made **in studies** are true, which makes it tough to answer, because obviously you don't accept such studies as sufficient evidence. Then **you speculate** that the number of car accidents should have gone up - but no-one else is making that claim. Perhaps they understand that there are too many confounding factors (better cars & roads, better training and other interventions, lower drink-driving rates, higher seat-belt wearing rates, lower car-ownership amongst youths, etc.)

Comment: Some ways to fix it: Find someone making the unlikely claim. Ask for empirical evidence that phone users have a higher accident rate than a control group. (Oh, and you might find distinguishing between texting and talking on the phone helps.) Accept evidence from the "lab" - e.g. the study you quote.

Comment: @Oddthinking: The studies purport to claim that a relatively common activity is more dangerous than the benchmark for dangerous driving. I would expect that if that is the case then there would be some correlation between the number of people who can perform that activity and either a crash or fatality rate.

Comment: @Gabe: That's a simple fallacy, unless you first account for all the confounding factors. Without evidence, I would bet a lot of drivers only text significantly in stop-start traffic, which I'd predict leads to more rear-end taps, but not many more deaths. But that's just my speculation, so it is out of scope in a question.

Comment: Driving itself is believed to be a dangerous activity. Yet as driving rates have dramatically increased over the past century life expectancy has actually *increased*. Explain

Comment: "To take just a short time period, during the four years between 2003 and 2007 nearly 100M new cell phone subscribers were added" Only a tiny percentage of those new cell phone users will use their phones while driving, you suggestion that this is equivalent to "so many millions of newly-effectively-drunk drivers on the roads" is not correct

Comment: @RichardTingle: I updated the question to provide a soure claiming that half of all drivers reported to driving while on the phone in the prior 30 days. I don't think that percentage is tiny.

Comment: I think you also have to distinguish what drivers are doing with their phones.  I've seen a lot of very dangerous phone behavior but I don't believe there is an inherent danger that can't be avoided.

Comment: @LorenPechtel: For the most part, the literature discusses using the phone to converse, whether hand-held or hands-free.

Comment: @Gabe I've seen people get into far too serious conversations while driving.  I've seen people take notes about the phone call.

Comment: @LorenPechtel: I would say that taking notes would not be covered, but any other normal conversations would.

Comment: You write:"There have been numerous studies that show how using a phone while driving is more distracting than other non-driving tasks and even worse than driving while intoxicated". Doesn't that answer your question? What exactly is the claim that you are doubting?

Comment: @DJClayworth: If it's so dangerous, where are all the extra accidents that result? I would expect that there would be some number of accidents or deaths attributable to it, which would go up with the number of phones. I don't see it, so I am doubting that the studies really show what they purport to show.

Comment: The studies you show does not show that driving while texting is more dangerous than driving while drunk.  They show that driving while texting is harder than driving while drunk.  However drunk driving is not just a problem due to impaired reaction times.  Alkohol also impairs risk evaluation, which handeling phones does not do.

Comment: @Taemyr: That's an interesting observation! But does it explain why phone users do worse on driving tests than alcohol users?

Comment: You are unlikely to get anything more than anecdotal evidence which may not be what this site wants.

Comment: @NeilMeyer: Do you think that's because the evidence doesn't exist, or that nobody has looked for it? I suspect that the evidence isn't there to be found.

Comment: You have too many questions here, and not a verifiable claim. Yes, driving while using a cell phone is dangerous (mostly because of the driving part). The "distracted" part is what makes using a cell phone while driving dangerous, and multiple studies have shown that talking with someone in the same vehicle is just as dangerous as using a cell phone to talk to someone. Driving while legally drunk isn't that dangerous (the legal limit has been lowered quite a bit). Yes, driving has become less dangerous due to cars becoming safer, emergency rooms becoming better, etc. What is the claim you want

Comment: I'd suggest pairing the question down to the simple claim in the title and leaving out the speculation as it just distracts from the central claim. The key issue is how you evaluate the impact of phone use *independently* from all the confounding factors. Leave the speculation about evidence to *answers* and take them out of the question.

Comment: @user1873: [My statistics](http://responsibility.org/drunk-driving/drunk-driving-fatalities-national-statistics) say drunk drivers caused 10,322 fatalities in the US in 2012. How many were caused by cell phone users?

Comment: @matt_black: OK, I pared down the question. What do you think?

Comment: @Gabe, 350 in 2011, but they believe that number is underreported. Not sure what your point is though? 33k died in auto accidents, and the [10,332 drunk driving fatalites](http://www.nhtsa.gov/About+NHTSA/Press+Releases/NHTSA+Data+Confirms+Traffic+Fatalities+Increased+In+2012) were mostly from people over twice the legal limit (blood alcohol concentration 0.15 instead of 0.08)

Comment: @user1873: My question is whether using a phone while driving is dangerous. If there were only 350 phone-driving fatalities in all of 2011, it is no more dangerous than sleeping or bathing! I don't see how anybody can claim that it's more dangerous than drunk driving.

Comment: @Gabe, you are confusing the issue (you might want to correct the title). These are two separate questions, **Is using a phone while driving dangerous?** and "Is using a phone while driving **more** dangerous than drunk driving?" The answer to the first question is yes (but mostly because of the driving). The second question might be yes, depending upon what you count as drunk driving.

Comment: BTW, [everything is dangerous](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/10026/is-there-no-risk-free-level-of-second-hand-smoke/10027#10027)

Comment: @user1873: I have changed the title per your suggestion to remove ambiguity. However at 350 deaths in one year, it doesn't sound like it's more dangerous than driving without a phone, let alone while drunk.

Comment: Driving with a blindfold would probably be very dangerous, but it doesn't cause many deaths per year.

Comment: @ChrisW: Indeed, it's so manifestly dangerous that I've never seen anybody do it. Driving while talking on a phone is so ubiquitous, though, that sources report anywhere from 1% to 9% of US drivers are on a phone at any given time. If 1% of drivers cause 1% of fatalities, I'd call that "chance" rather than "dangerous".

Answer (score -4):

tl;dr: No.

Since using a phone while driving is not more dangerous than simply driving, the question is equivalent to asking if it is dangerous to drive while drunk.

It may be a bit surprising to learn that it is not dangerous to use a phone while driving, as there are many studies which claim to have found the opposite. Unfortunately, road safety is an area where a huge amount of research can be found which is of very low quality. While your first link is now broken, I can follow the UK one and that study is of a quality I would describe as laughably and appallingly poor. It has these problems:

- very low sample size - only 20 participants
- very restricted participant type - only experienced drivers
- no driving was tested - it was all in a simulator
- no risk or danger occurred - participants knew that there was no chance of harm to anyone
- no measure of risk was used - the measure was of irrelevant proxies: speed control, response time, ability to answer questions
- self reporting - drivers own opinions are considered worth reporting
- highly biased research - the researchers are obsessed with danger to the extent that the word "safer" does not appear in the report, with the comparison either being reversed (X is more dangerous than Y rather than Y is safer than X) or being expressed as "less dangerous"

For anyone who wants to read the study for themselves, it's at [TRL547](https://trl.co.uk/reports/TRL547)

When reading studies on driving, there are a few red flags which should make you disregard any study as probably worthless. One of the most common is the use of a bogus proxy, and the most common of these is reaction time. It is well known that older people have slower reaction times than younger people, yet it is also well known that young people are much worse drivers than older people (especially by insureance companies who stand to lose a lot of money if they get that wrong). Consequently, reaction time is such a bad proxy that its use immediately calls into question the competence of any study. Other bogus proxies are things which are irrelevant to safety - such as lane following precision, or vehicle following precision. These are not quite so bad in that they may indicate driving ability in some narrow circumstances (e.g. selecting racing drivers) but are irrelevant to safety.

Another red flag is driver's opinions. People are extremely bad at self-assessment and there are many notorious psychological effects in this area, so no study should even bother asking drivers their opinions except as a way of suggesting further research.

In road safety, the only things that count are:

- deaths
- serious injuries
- minor injuries
- property damage

People's opinions do not count. People's subjective feelings of danger do not count. Proxies do not count unless there is strong evidence of strong correlation with one of the factors that do count and proper consideration has been taken of confounding variables.

Ok. So it's time to show evidence why phone use is safe while driving.
For this I cite [Driving under the (Cellular) Influence](https://www.aeaweb.org/articles?id=10.1257/pol.5.3.92) (paywalled)
which seems to be quite strong. Here is the abstract:

> We investigate the causal link between driver cell phone use and
>   crash rates by exploiting a natural experiment induced by the 9 pm
>   price discontinuity that characterizes a majority of recent cellular
>   plans. We first document a 7.2 percent jump in driver call
>   likelihood at the 9 pm threshold. Using a prior period as a
>   comparison, we next document no corresponding change in the relative
>   crash rate. Our estimates imply an upper bound in the crash risk
>   odds ratio of 3.0, which rejects the 4.3 asserted by Redelmeier and
>   Tibshirani (1997). Additional panel analyses of cell phone ownership
>   and cellular bans confirm our result.

Note that this compares actual crash numbers - not proxies, and phone
use is during real driving - not simulations. Possibly the strongest
part is that the drivers were completely unaware that they were being
studied, so their behaviour was completely natural.

In fact, the most surprising thing in that study is that no
correlation was found. Even if phone use is completely safe, I'd
expect studies to find it correlated with crashes. This is because of
driver attitudes - drivers vary between very careful and quite
reckless, and I would expect that, since people are so often told that
phone use is dangerous, the more careful drivers would be more likely
to refrain from using a phone while driving. Assuming that more
careful drivers are less likely to have crashes, this should result in
a non-causal correction between phone use and crashes.

Most driving research fails to take into account the most important
property of drivers - they learn. There is no doubt that experienced
drivers are safer than novices, yet when mobile phones started
appearing the research effectively tested novice use of phones while
driving. Even if that is more dangerous, there's no a priori reason to
assume that this is uniquely difficult and that drivers can never
learn to do it safely.

Comment: "It is well known that older people have slower reaction times than younger people, yet it is also well known that young people are much worse drivers than older people." Do you think, just perhaps, there might be other confounding factors that might explain this? Less driving experience, different risk taking profiles, more kms driven per day, cheaper cars... just as a start.

Comment: The main paper you cite is interesting, but I think you are leaning on it too hard. They report an upper confidence limit of the odds ratio of 3.0, so it is plausible to them that the risk of accidents increases. Table 1 undermines your argument that all other studies rely on proxies. They explicitly address the question comparing it to drunk driving, and I think you should quote that.

Comment: It should also be noted that they are discussing talking on the phone. Based on the adverts I have seen, authorities are more worried about texting.

Comment: @oddthinking - 1) There is no mention of texting in the question, so I have answered the question asked, not the one you imagined was asked. 2) I refer to reaction time as a bad proxy, so *of course* there are confounding factors - that's the whole point I am making - that reaction time is not a suitable thing to measure. 3) I do not rely on the cited study. I rely on the fact that the claim that using a phone while driving is significantly dangerous is itself fairly implausible and so needs very strong evidence, I only cite the study to show that even more evidence is required.

Comment: 1) The question is about phone use. This study only looked at one aspect of phone use (phone calls) and didn't look at other aspects (including texting, maps and games). I strongly suspect phone calls are a minority use in by drivers in 2019 - so it doesn't address the complete question. My objection remains, despite your dismissal of it as imagined.

Comment: 2) If the studies look for a subject's *drop* in reaction time, due to alcohol or phone use, rather than raw reaction times, it is still a proxy, but it appears to be a very strong one. I agree such a proxy needs to be validated, but your dismissal of it because old drivers have fewer crashes seems premature.

Comment: 3) We seem to have very different priors. Phone use seems a clear and obvious distraction, and it doesn't seem implausible at all that it might be dangerous, especially when your study itself cites many other studies demonstrating that it is dangerous, even if finds the results disagree with them. I remain open-minded about whether alcohol or phones are more dangerous - I suspect the answer is "it depends on alcohol levels and type of phone usage", but one study wasn't convincing to me.

Comment: You left out the most significant part of road safety. How does the person's driving affect the safety of others on the road? It is nearly impossible to get good statistics on this because many 'bad' drivers leave the trail of destruction behind them while they go along their oblivious and merry way.